# How to make navigation bar's sub view pushed with view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a `UISegmentedController` on my `navigationBar`. The segmented control was added using below code:

```
@property (nonatomic) UISegmentedControl *segView;
...
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _segView = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"Seg1", @"Seg2"]];
    [_segView setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
    [_segView addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:_segView];
}
```

When I push a view into `navigationController`, the segmented control is still there, so the recently pushed view's title will be overlapped with the segmented control.

[image]

How to make the segmented control to be pushed into the stack with the previous view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding `UISegmentedControl` as `subView` in `navigationBar` set as `titleView` of `navigationItem` like this.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = _segView;
```

Comment: Just what I need.  :)